# What is diff between jdk1.7_99 and jdk1.7_271

Tags: java, java-7

I want to see the diff between jdk1.7_99 and jdk1.7_271.

Is there anyway I can see the diff between two? like any deprecated method is there which I must know. If we updated our system with jdk1.7_271, will there be any problem?

Thank You.

EDIT

I got it from the comments that how to check the differences between these versions. Thank you.

Comment: Do your own **research** and read through all the [**Release Notes**](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/7-support-relnotes.html) from JDK 7u101 to JDK 7u271, all 18 of them. Don't expect us to aggregate them for you! --- Question down-voted for lack of research.

Comment: Ok I got it. Thank you Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated from this [link](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/DEV/Java+Product+Version+Policy#:%7E:text=A%20minor%20version%20has%20the,deprecate%2C%20but%20not%20remove%2C%20versions&text=Java%20API%3A%20may%20add%2Fdeprecate%2C%20but%20not%20remove%2C%20APIs):

**Minor Version Compatibility**

A minor version has the following compatibility when compared with a previous minor version with the same major version number:

- Java Source and Target Level: identical
- Compatible Java Versions: may add/deprecate, but not remove, versions
- Supported Java Versions: may
  add versions or remove deprecated versions
- Java API: may add/deprecate, but not remove, APIs
- 3rd Party Libraries: may add/upgrade, but not remove, libraries; upgrades to libraries must follow the Java API compatibility rules
- Configuration: may add/deprecate, but not remove, options/properties/beans/etc.
- Protocol Messages: may add, but not remove, new protocols/options; protocol
  implementations in common with previous minor versions remain
  wire-compatible
- Storage Formats (API): may add to, but not remove
  from, formats in ways that would not be expected to break standard
  tools interacting with the data
- Storage Formats (non-API): may change
  in ways that render older minor versions incapable of working with
  the data

**The result of this is that upgrading from one minor version to another does not require any change other than installing the version to be used and updating the builds of any third-party plugins used.**

**Existing configuration files will work unchanged, but may need to be modified to take advantage of new features. Downgrading to an older minor version may require removing configuration options introduced in newer versions.**

Note that in adding APIs, abstract or interface methods are not added to existing public interfaces or classes to guarantee compile-time compatibility for existing extensions.